# Get rid of complex results

Tags: complex-analysis

One of the roots of the cubic equation obtained by the Cardano formula:

\begin{equation} \label{sdw}
 \begin{split}
\alpha(\xi, \delta) = &\delta \cdot \xi +  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( -T(\xi, \delta) + \frac{\delta^2 -\delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + a_2 / (6 \cdot a_4)}{T(\xi, \delta)}\right) - \\
& - \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \left( T(\xi, \delta) + \frac{\delta^2 -\delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + a_2 / (6 \cdot a_4)}{T(\xi, \delta)}\right),
  \end{split} 
\end{equation}

where
$$ T(\xi, \delta) = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle(\delta^2 - \delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + a_2 / (6 \cdot a_4))^3 + \delta^6 \cdot \xi^2 \cdot (\xi^2 -1)^2} + \delta^3 \cdot (\xi^3 - \xi)}. $$

The first term of the root expression is negative:
$$ \left(\delta^2 - \delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + a_2 / (6 \cdot a_4)\right)^3 < 0, $$

which leads to complex results when calculating $T(\xi, \delta). $

To obtain a valid result in the ratio $\alpha$, the terms, except for the first, are complex conjugate pairs, the addition of which turns the imaginary part to zero.

However, in this form, further analysis of the expression is difficult. Therefore, we will replace the variables:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
A &= \delta^2 - \delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + \frac{a_2}{6 \cdot a_4}, \\
B &= A^3 + \delta^6 \cdot \xi^2 \cdot \left(\xi^2 - 1 \right)^2, \\
C &= \delta^3 \cdot \left(\xi^3 - \xi \right),
  \end{split} 
\end{equation*}
then

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
T(\xi, \delta) &= \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle A^3 + \delta^6 \cdot \xi^2 \cdot (\xi^2 -1)^2} + \delta^3 \cdot (\xi^3 - \xi)}, \\ 
T(\xi, \delta) &= \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + \delta^3 \cdot (\xi^3 - \xi)}, \\  
T(\xi, \delta) &= \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C},
   \end{split} 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \alpha_(\xi, \delta) = &\delta \cdot \xi +  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( -\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C} + \frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}\right) - \\
  & - \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \left( \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C} + \frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}\right),
 \end{split} 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   \alpha(\xi, \delta) = &\delta \cdot \xi - \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}{2} + \frac{A}{2 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}} - \\
   & - \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}{2} - \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot A}{2\cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}},
  \end{split} 
\end{equation*}

Let's write out complex-conjugate pairs:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}{2} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{A}{2 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}; \;\;\;\;
 \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}{2} \Leftrightarrow - \frac{j \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot A}{2\cdot\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}}
\end{equation*}

Or a shorter form of entry:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
   \alpha(\xi, \delta) &= \delta \cdot \xi - Re \left[\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}\right] - Re\left[ j \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C}\right]  \\
\alpha(\xi, \delta) &= \delta \cdot \xi - Re \left[\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle B} + C} \cdot (1 + j \cdot \sqrt{3})\right] \\
\alpha(\xi, \delta) &=  \delta \cdot \xi - Re \left[\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\displaystyle(\delta^2 - \delta^2 \cdot \xi^2 + a_2 / (6 \cdot a_4))^3 + \delta^6 \cdot \xi^2 \cdot (\xi^2 -1)^2} + \delta^3 \cdot (\xi^3 - \xi)}\cdot \right. \\ 
& \left. \cdot (1 + j \cdot \sqrt{3})\right] \\
  \end{split} 
\end{equation*}

But even in this form, the expression is difficult to analyze. I want to completely get rid of taking the real part and the imaginary unit, since the answer always turns out to be valid anyway. To do this, I want to manually expand the brackets and discard the imaginary part, but due to the presence of roots, I get a huge expression when opening the brackets.

if the answer is always a real number, then there is an expression where there will be no imaginary part at once?

Comment: Don't know why you'd ever think of "*taking an integer part*" here. Just use that $\,\operatorname{Re}(\lambda z) = \lambda \operatorname{Re}(z)\,$ when $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't know what is exactly $[ z ]$, when $z$ is complex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sure that the symbols "[" and "]" are just used a parenthesis here, not indicating the "integer part" as you assume. Using them instead of the normal parenthesis "(" and ")" here makes it easy to see to what exactly the "Re" part applies to, namely the whole term.

Comment: Yes, square brackets indicate that taking the real part applies to the whole expression

Comment: I clarified my question, wrote it in more detail